How to use ViewModel correctly to share, mutate or observe data between different layers in an android app using Jetpack Compose?
I am new to Jetpack compose, when following the example video from https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/state at 4:00
I found that the viewModel() is missing in my project.
class HelloViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _name = MutableLiveData("View Model")
    val name: LiveData<String> = _name

    fun setName(newName: String) {
        _name.value = newName
    }

}

// In the latest version of Jetpack compose
// viewModel() is missing here as a default value for helloViewModel variable
// And I don't know what dependencies should be implemented for my project
@Composable
fun ViewModelTest(helloViewModel: HelloViewModel = viewModel()) {

    // This line errors, since helloModel.name doesn't have a method called `observeAsState()`
    val name by helloViewModel.name.observeAsState()

    // A text composable
    Text(name.value)

    // A Button, once clicked, replace the text of Text composable to "ViewModel changed"
    Button(onClick = { helloViewModel.setName("ViewModel changed") }) {
        Text(text = "Text")
    }
}

Any suggestions?
// default value for helloViewModel should be viewModel()
fun ViewModelTest(helloViewModel: HelloViewModel = viewModel())

// observe the name as a state
val name by helloViewModel.name.observeAsState()


Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

To be able to use the viewModel() function, you need to add the following dependency to your module's build.gradle file:
for build.gradle (Groovy):
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.5'

for build.gradle.kts (Kotlin):
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.5")


One related question, what if I want to use Shared ViewModel, is it right to pass it as parameter to the Compose screen?

It is okay to pass it to the screen Composable, but you should not pass it down further the Compose hierarchy, as this is very bad for testability. Instead, only pass the needed properties or functions from the ViewModel down to child Composables.
